# How to calculate date after 14 days

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two dates and i want to check condition that `CLO/LO issued date past 14 days grace period fall in the reporting period.` I have two dates. I tried  condition that

```
LOSA_CR_DETAIL_Z.lo_dt > 14 + (:endDate - :startDate)
```

But this gives me error that

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I think this will give me 14 days not date. How can i calculate condition that `date > 14 days plus date` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the introduction to your query, is sounds like you want to check if `LOSA_CR_DETAIL_Z.lo_dt + 14 day` falls within a specific date interval.

If so, a condition like

```
LOSA_CR_DETAIL_Z.lo_dt + 14 BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

should be what you are looking for.